# What is the purpose of syntax support of npm module depcheck?

Tags: javascript, npm

Looking at the [docs](https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck) I don't understand what the Syntax support means. Does it mean that if you're using es6's import, you need to `npm install -g depcheck emmascript2015` or something similar in order for depcheck to see which dependencies you're using? How does this work with React JSX as that isn't what's used to require modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depcheck does something really simple. It reads your source code and figure out what modules you are using.

Obviously to do that it needs to parse your source code. And obviously to parse source code it needs to understand its syntax.

So the syntax support simply means that depcheck can parse es5, es6, es7, jsx, coffee, typescript, sass and scss for module dependency without compiling any of those files.

Comment: so is npm install -g depcheck emmascript2015  the correct grammar if I want it to be able to parse es6? should I just install all of the syntax so that I don't need to worry about it again?

Comment: No. Depcheck only needs external modules to parse two languages: typescript and sass (read the docs **carefully**). Also, don't be confused by `npm install -g depcheck sass`. It's not a special syntax. It's doing `npm install -g depcheck; npm install -g sass`